# Using AppleScript to add images to Pages document

Tags: applescript, automator, pages, graphics

I am trying to automate the task of inserting an image to a pages document, then change it's arrangement properties to something that normal people use (like "move with text" and "inline with text") instead of the default "stay on page".

This is proving to be extremely difficult.

So far I managed to accomplish two basic things: import the image and use System Events to click side pane buttons to change the properties. The trouble I have is selecting/highlighting the image after importing it so that the "Arrange" side panel appears so System Events can see it, since the image is normally deselected after importing.

```
   -- import image at file path thisImageFile
make new image with properties {file:thisImageFile}
```

(sometimes this throws an error for no apparent reason.)

I couldn't find a way to tell Pages to select the image directly, so I reverted to System Events, but System Events seems to not like to click in document areas. I figured out that Automator can record "Watch Me Do" user actions so I tried that. It works fine to select the image properly (most of the time), but I'd rather not use this function if I can.

Related note: I also discovered that items generated by "Watch Me Do" can be exported to AppleScript by dragging them into an Automator AppleScript action. And only within Automator, can't drag it to ScriptEditor because of course not. That reveals the command and attributes of whatever UI elements were interacted with, like this:

```
    -- Drag the scroll thumb in the scroll area.
delay 0.641042
set timeoutSeconds to 2.0
set uiScript to "click scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of window \"test doc for scripting.pages\" of application process \"Pages\""
my doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)

on doWithTimeout(uiScript, timeoutSeconds)
    set endDate to (current date) + timeoutSeconds
    repeat
        try
            run script "tell application \"System Events\"
" & uiScript & "
end tell"
            exit repeat
        on error errorMessage
            if ((current date) > endDate) then
                error "Can not " & uiScript
            end if
        end try
    end repeat
end doWithTimeout
```

which boils down to:

```
tell application "System Events" to click scroll area 1 of splitter group 1 of front window of application process "Pages"
```

The revealing of attributes this way is useful for finding deeply nested UI Elements for System Events to interact with, without extensive guessing and without Xcode (which I don't have access to).

But when you run this script directly, it has no noticeable effect and also has no error. So as always there must be some secret sauce in the "Watch Me Do" function.

I also tried just telling System Events to click coordinates over the image

```
tell application "System Events" to click at {1400,600}
```

that works for clicking buttons and stuff, but does nothing in terms of selecting objects in the Pages document. When it supposedly clicks the image in the doc, literally nothing happens, even when it clicks it a bunch of times.

Any ideas? Am I missing something, or is this just a lost cause like so many other of my AppleScript ventures? I guess I could use the record feature, but that just feels like giving up...plus it's slower.

EDIT:

to accomplish highlighting/focusing Pages on an image in the body of a Pages doc I ended up just telling Pages to set the image rotation to some arbitrary value. This works well enough because the images I wanted to work with were predictably always the first/only image on the page. So I'm just leaving it at that.

Here's what I ended up with to replace an image in Pages:

1. select an image in Finder
2. select an image to replace on current Pages page
3. query the old image properties for use later
4. add the new image and set the properties
5. tell System Events to click the arrangement buttons in the side panel (that I found the names for from Watch Me Do)

   ```
   set thisImageFile to choose file with prompt "Select an image"
   tell application "Pages"    
   activate        
   tell front document to tell current page        
       set oldImage to image 1         
       tell oldImage to set its rotation to 91         
       --need to change oldImage to Stay on Page in order to query its width property          
       tell application "System Events"            
           --Arrange               
           click radio button 3 of radio group 1 of splitter group 1 of front window of application process "Pages"                
           --Stay on Page              
           click radio button 1 of radio group 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of front window of application process "Pages"               
       end tell            
       set oldWidth to width of oldImage           
       delete oldImage         

       set theImage to make new image with properties {file:thisImageFile}         
       tell theImage to set its width to oldWidth          
       tell theImage to set its position to {0, 0}         
       tell theImage to set its rotation to 90         
   end tell        
   tell application "System Events"        
       --Arrange           
       click radio button 3 of radio group 1 of splitter group 1 of front window of application process "Pages"            
       --Move with Text            
       click radio button 2 of radio group 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of front window of application process "Pages"           
       --text wrap drop down and Inline with Text          
       click pop up button 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of front window of application process "Pages"           
       click menu item "Inline with Text" of menu 1 of pop up button 1 of scroll area 2 of splitter group 1 of front window of application process "Pages"         
   end tell
   end tell
   ```

Comment: FWIW, after using the 'watch me do' feature, you can then edit the resulting script to remove unnecessary parts and reduce delays.